# iOS 8 Core Location works everytime on WiFi, intermittent on 4G

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, core-location

So it works when I'm on WiFi.  But on 4G, it only works if I had been on Wifi and it already has the location.  A lot of times without WiFi, the phone will say it's using my location but its not updating the label nor is it uploading the coordinates to the server.  Here's the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (nil == locationManager)
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    if ([self->locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [self->locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
    CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];
    NSString *locationLat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    NSString *locationLong = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];

    latLongLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lat: %@ - Long%@",locationLat,locationLong];
    [self postLocation:locationLat secondArg:locationLong];

}
- (void)postLocation: (NSString *)latitudeString secondArg:(NSString *)longitudeString {

//POST COORDINATES TO MY SERVER

}

- (IBAction)startUpdating:(id)sender {

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}
```

Comment: Are you substantially moving from one location to another when doing your tests? `CLLocationManager` won't send you any location updates if you are too close to the original location. Also, did you test your app in the Simulator? You could use the predefined circuits around Cupertino to check that your app works as expected, apart from the 4G/Wi-Fi network issues...

Comment: My app works on the SIM, using static location like Apple, or moving on the freeway.  It also works on my phone when I am using Wifi.  If I am using WiFi when I start up the app and press the startUpdating() button, It shows my Lat Longs on the labels as well as calls for the postLocation() 100% of the time.  However if I start my app without WiFi, and press the startUpdating button, It doesn't work.  The only time it works is if I was recently on WiFi.  I am out of ideas...

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you found where the problem was?

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that when you are on 4G, the location updates still work fine (although wifi triangulation makes them a bit more precise but only Apple knows how, as the implementation is private), BUT there might be an issue sending those values to the server quickly or reliably enough via 4G connection. (for example in London it is slow as hell with so many people around)

You might narrow the debugging by simply logging the location update directly to some UIlabel on your view, and not going through server infrastructure.

AS a last resort I would make sure 
that you set your `CLActivityType` property to `CLActivityTypeFitness`
and `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` is set to `NO`.

Comment: That was my initial suspicion, however the label does not update as well.  By default the app opens up with initial value of "NO LOCATION" on the label.  It stays that way on 4G... Ill test some more by moving around while on 4G

Comment: It turns out, on cellular data, it does not update until I move significantly... On Wifi, it will update anyway if I am stationary.  It is important for my app to update as soon as the button is pressed (even if it takes a couple of seconds to figure out location).  Any ideas how I can force it to update?

Comment: I had a similar problem of "updates starting to flow in"...but for iBeacon. in your case, you can define a convenient CLCircularRegion, then request your locmanager to do this
[self.locationManager requestStateForRegion:region]; right after you initialize the manager.
And then handle the delegate response - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
      didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state
              forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
Try this experiment, it might trigger updates to flow.